# Sufficient conditions on the marginals for exchangeability of the joint distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Consider a random vector $X$ of dimension $L\times 1$ with cumulative distribution function $F$ absolutely continuous. Let $F_1,..., F_L$ denote the marginal cdf's.

Assume that the probability distribution of $X$ is exchangeable, i.e., 
$$
(\star) \hspace{1cm}F(x_1,..., x_L)=F(x_{\pi(1)},...,x_{\pi(L)})
$$
for any permutation $\pi$ of $\{1,...,L\}$.

**Question**: are there any sufficient conditions on $F_1,..., F_L$ implying $(\star)$?

(For example, I think it should be that $F_1=...=F_L$ but this is necessary and not sufficient for exchangeability).

Comment: Any condition that *only concerns the marginal CDF's* will **not** be sufficient for $(\star)$.

Comment: OK, I see, it makes sense. Are there necessary conditions on the margins, other than identical margins?

Comment: No, since  based on *any* CDF $G:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ we can construct an $F:\mathbb R^L\to\mathbb R$ that satisfies $(\star)$. This by taking $F(x_1,\dots,x_L)=G(x_1)\times\cdots\times G(x_L)$. And in that case $F_i=G$ for every $i$, so we have equality of the marginals.

Comment: @Vera could you help me with this question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2952758/from-the-marginal-to-the-joint-cdf in case you have some time

Comment: You might be inspired from my answer to your other question, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2953168/350942. 

It is not sufficient to assume only that the marginals are identical, $F_1 = \cdots = F_L$. What you are looking for is identical marginals and exchangable copulas, such as multivariate exchangeable Archimedean copulas. A copula $C$ is exchangeable exactly when your (*) holds for $C$ rather than F. Firstly, the marginals have to be identical. With that established, we need another condition. Here we can focus on only the dependency structure given by the copula.