# Functions of exchangeable random vectors

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Consider the random vector $\begin{pmatrix}
X_0\\ X_1\\ X_2
\end{pmatrix}$ with joint cdf $F$.

Consider the random vector $ \begin{pmatrix}
Y_3\\
Y_4\\
Y_5
\end{pmatrix}\equiv \begin{pmatrix}
X_1-X_0\\
X_2-X_0\\
X_1-X_2
\end{pmatrix}$ with joint cdf $G$.

We say that $X_0, X_1, X_2$ are exchangeable if 
$$
F(x_0, x_1, x_2)=F(x_{\pi(0)}, x_{\pi(1)}, x_{\pi(2)})
$$
for any permutation of $\{0,1,2\}$ and for any $(x_0, x_1, x_2)\in \mathbb{R}^3$. We say that $Y_3, Y_4, Y_5$ are exchangeable if 
$$
G(y_3, y_4, y_5)=G(y_{\varphi(3)}, y_{\varphi(4)}, y_{\varphi(5)})
$$
for any permutation of $\{3,4,5\}$ and for any $(y_3, y_4, y_5)\in \mathbb{R}^3$.

Is it true that

(1) If $X_0, X_1, X_2$ is exchangeable then $Y_3, Y_4, Y_5$ are exchangeable?

(2) If $Y_3, Y_4, Y_5$  is exchangeable then $X_0, X_1, X_2$ are exchangeable?

Comment: Can you check your second line. I would guess it might be $$\begin{pmatrix}
Y_3\\
Y_4\\
Y_5
\end{pmatrix}\equiv \begin{pmatrix}
X_0-X_1\\
X_2-X_0\\
X_1-X_2
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @Henry Thanks: why? Does it matter?

Comment: Suppose the $X_i$ independently each take the values $0$ or $1$ with equal probability.  Then consider the possible values for the $Y$s using your  definition and mine

Comment: @Henry Thanks. Given my definition of $(Y_3, Y_4, Y_5)$, we have for example that $\mathbb{P}((Y_3, Y_4, Y_5)=(1,-1,1))=0$. This is still the case for any permutation of $\{3,4,5\}$. Could you help me to see the issue? Are some zero probabilities not replicated under permutations?

Comment: With my example and your definition, $\mathbb{P}((Y_3, Y_4, Y_5)=(1,1,0))>0$ but $\mathbb{P}((Y_3, Y_4, Y_5)=(0,1,1))=0$.  My guess was this was not what was initended